# Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.0.1', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources

Tags: java, android-gradle-plugin, jetbrains-ide

I attemtped to make a long post with all the code that was relevant, but no matter what I did, it would not accept it, saying it was not properly formatted. So I am going minimal. I have seen several posts that were similar, but I do not know how to resolve what I am getting for an error.

Build file '/home/jason/AndroidStudioProjects/GBTest07/build.gradle' line: 3

Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.0.1', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Try:

> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Exception is:
  org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.0.1', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:8.0.1')
  Searched in the following repositories:
  maven(https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/)

I have tried (unsuccessfully) to change the gradle version, and the java version, but I am new, and I am not sure what gradle/java works together the best. I am not sure that changing the version would even solve this issue. I am not running a VPN, or a proxy.